# Manage Product Magento Admin show empty page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have did migration from magento 1.7 to 1.9 and i have saved same database , but whene testing the result i found this url (Catalog => Manage Products) gives empty page not show grid list product.

Any Suggestions to solve this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to check the error logs (PHP error log, exception.log, system.log).

I think that this problem can be caused by third party extension, which is not compatible with new Magento version.

Try to turn off all extensions which are not the Magento core modules.